# Facebook iframe web app div scrolling to bottom

Tags: css, facebook, html, scroll, overflow

I have a facebook iframe web app that opens a jquery dialog with an onclick. The jquery dialog has the below css. When the dialog opens the div always scrolls to the bottom. Is there a way to make the div start at the top and not the bottom? It seems facebook doesnt let you use some of the jquery and javascript functions to do this.

```
#dialog {
    max-width: 525px;
    max-height: 525px;
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: can you share you link where have you tried this ?

Comment: @samitha the app is still in development so I can't share at this time.

Comment: can you share any screenshot ?

Comment: @samitha I can not at this time

Answer (score 0):

```
   #dialog {
        position:absolute;
        top:20%;
        left:20%:
        z-index:999;
        max-width: 525px;
        max-height: 525px;
        overflow: auto;
        font-family: Times New Roman;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 18px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
```

if you want to stay the dialog box in the same place u have used  position:absolute;

Comment: the dialog box is in the correct place. The content of the dialog box is the issue. the div is set to scroll. When it displays it starts at the bottom of the scrolled content not the top. putting position absolute will not fix this issue.